# Execute script php with no reload page

Tags: php, shell, apache2

my index.html

```
form action="h-left.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" id="jQueryButton5" onclick="window.reload(true);return false;" name="" value="left" style="position:absolute;left:740px;top:120px;width:101px;height:28px;z-index:4;">
</form>
```

my h-left.php

```
<?php
header('Location: /aisoy2/index.html');  # redirection vers page principal 
exec('python /home/pi/py/head-left.py');
?>
```

I want execute this script without reload the page,

Comment: run the php script with an AJAX call

Comment: PHP is service side language. You have to post request to the server to execute PHP code. If you want to do it with out page reload, use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have jQuery run an AJAX request to your php script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax for that, PHP will reload the page because it goes to the server.

It's more easy to use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "yourphppage.php",
  // parameters that you want to pass
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  // When the request complete
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

More info: [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Call php script via AJAX.

See this page: Ajax using jQuery: [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Jquery Ajax. This is simple and straightforward.

Inside your html file

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#jQueryButton5").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"h-left.php",success:function(result){
    //Success 
  }});
});

});
</script>
```

Read this tutorial :

[Jquery Ajax Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)